# Why is my splash screen work only on some devices?

Tags: android, xml, flutter, splash-screen

So here is my desired splash screen:

[image]

And here is how I implemented it:

1. inside `android/app/src/main/res/darwable` added the image of the splash screen (`launch_image.png`) and the gradient background xml file (`gradient_background.xml`)
2. inside `android/app/src/main/res/values` created a file named `colors.xml` that's going to hold the colors to display in the splash screen:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name='gradientStartColor'>#68CDF6</color>
    <color name='gradientEndColor'>#80D325</color>
</resources>
```

3. added these lines to the `gradient_background.xml`:

```dart
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/gradientStartColor"
        android:endColor="@color/gradientEndColor"
        android:angle="135" />    
</shape>
```

4. finally inside the `launch_background.xml` I added these lines:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_background"/> 

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/launch_image" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

And since there is two folders named `drawable` and `drawable-v21`, I copied the content of the first folder and put it inside the second folder because I don't really know what the secon folder is for. The splash screen is perfectly working on my physical device (Redmi Note 8 Pro, Android) but in my Pixel3a emulator it's not working, it gives me a green background with a Flutter icon in the middle.

[image]

But again, in my physical it's working perfectly.

Comment: What is the API of your Pixel3a emulator?

Comment: @C.F.G How can I know this ?

Comment: What is your editor? Android studio?

Comment: @C.F.G mainly I use VS Code, but I used Android Studio and I have it installed, so if you have a solution to find out what's my emulator's API using Android Studio or VS code I can do it

Comment: Android studio will show the API level of emulator on `Run` tab after build.

Answer (score 1):

After Android 12, has changed how SplashScreen work, so probably is the problem you are facing: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features/splash-screen?hl=pt-br

By default the app icon will be used in the SplashScreen, but you can change by an animated icon, like:

```
<item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/...</item>
```

and can change the color using:

```
<item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/...</item>
```

you can see another options in the link.